# JPA Attribute Override over Entity Subclass

Tags: java, jpa

Are we able to attribute override a entity subclass?
Here's my code structure:

table name: TEXT_VALUES 
columns: text, text_b, text_c

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEXT_VALUES")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR")
public class A {
  @Column(name = "text")
  String text;
}


@MappedSuperclass
public class B extends A {
  // more columns in here
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TEXT_C")
@AttributeOverride(name = "text", column = @Column(name = "TEXT_C"))
public class C extends  B {
 // more columns
}
```

The attribute override in class C doesn't seem to work at all.

Is this something @AttributeOverride can't do?

Comment: Any non-relation field is overriddeable using `@AttributeOverride`. But you are using single-table inheritance so overrides are utterly meaningless since the column exists in one table only.

Comment: The table design is such that there are 4 text fields.

Z is mapped to COL_A
A is mapped to COL_B
B should be mapped to COL_D

Comment: But an object of type C has ONE field "text". And so that has ONE column, not FOUR.

Comment: I've updated the question with code so it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The table "TEXT_VALUES" has 1 column representing that field. End of

Comment: You don't need to map all the columns in the top class.